# Solving the differential equation $f''=f'+f$, where $f$ is an exponential function meant to give a term of Fibonacci series

Tags: generating-functions, differential

I'm currently working through the H.S. Wilf's book [*generatingfunctionology*](https://www2.math.upenn.edu/%7Ewilf/gfology2.pdf), which is about generating functions, and have reached page 40 (or page 45 on the pdf) where the book is starting to deal with  calculus in exponential generating functions. Looking at Example 1 in the image below, I understand how the equation $f''= f' + f$ is created, but what I don't understand is how to solve it, which the author skims over. How would you solve equations like these?
[image: Image of problem]

Comment: This is a standard technique in any elementary differential equations course. You can read more about this technique [here](https://math.libretexts.org/Bookshelves/Differential_Equations/Book%3A_Differential_Equations_for_Engineers_(Lebl)/2%3A_Higher_order_linear_ODEs/2.2%3A_Constant_coefficient_second_order_linear_ODEs) for example.

Comment: Thanks for the help! I've just never seen something like this before. :)

Comment: @Icognito No worries!

Comment: $\displaystyle f = {\rm e}^{a x}$

Comment: Thanks for the help, this does work here!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's discuss how to solve linear differential equations

The simplest exaple is:
$\frac {dy}{dt} = y$

This is a separable diff eq.

$\int \frac 1y\ dy = \int\ dt\\
\ln y = t + C\\
y = C e^{t}$

Upping the degree of difficulty...

$\frac {dy}{dt} = ay\\
y = C e^{at}$

Note that: $\frac {dy}{dt} - ay = 0$ is the same problem.

And on to second-order diff eq.

$a\frac {d^2y}{dt^2} + b\frac {dy}{dt} + c = 0\\
(\frac {d}{dt} - \frac {-b + \sqrt{b^2-4ac}}{2a})(\frac {d}{dt} - \frac {-b - \sqrt{b^2-4ac}}{2a})y = 0$

If you think I am playing fast and loose with the differential operators, perhaps, I am.  But, this method holds up.  You can factor these like they are polynomials.

$y = C_1 e^{\frac {-b + \sqrt{b^2-4ac}}{2a}t} + C_2  e^{\frac {-b - \sqrt{b^2-4ac}}{2a}t}$

And if you don't believe me, start with the solution and see if it does not indeed solve the original diff eq.

$f'' - f' - f = 0\\
f = C_1 e^{\frac{1 + \sqrt 5}{2} t} + C_2e^{\frac{1 - \sqrt 5}{2} t}$

Comment: There are definitely problems with factoring like this. For example this does not reflect the additional steps involved when the roots of the characteristic polynomial have multiplicity, but I guess it works to some extent.

Comment: @AlanAbraham As I said, perhaps I am playing fast and loose.  However, most introductory texts on the subject begin with a characteristic polynomial, which is essentially the same thing with an additional step.   And, yes, there is an issue with mulitplicities that I have not addressed.

Comment: What additional steps would be required when the roots have multiplicity? Just curious

Comment: @Incognito If a root $r$ has multiplicity $m$, use a linear combination of $e^{rt}, te^{rt}, t^2e^{rt}, \dots, t^{m-1}e^{rt}$.

Answer (score 0):

This is a second-order linear differential equation.  Any textbook on differential equations will deal with these.